# Count the number of unique numbers/strings in a column, but limit the set to the rows that satisfy a certain condition in another column

Tags: arrays, excel, curly-braces, spill-range

This: "'=COUNTA(UNIQUE(D2:D724))"' works, but now I want to limit the input to this formula as follows:

only for the rows for which in another column a logical condition is satisfied, count the number of unique numbers/strings in column D for this limited set

So I want to limit the set D2:D724 in =COUNTA(UNIQUE(D2:D724))

I don't want to use filters for this, I want to do this with formulas.

Comment: Check out the FILTER() function (ie not manual filtering using the UI).

Comment: Thx, this seemed to work: =COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(E2:E724;V2:V724>-1;"error")))